# Difficulty clicking an anchor tag using href as locator

Tags: java, selenium, css-selectors, type-mismatch

How to locate identifiers in `Selenium` for the following line of code?

```
<a href="loginPage" class="loginBtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="rnr-loginPanel">Login</a>
```

I have tried:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a [contains ( @href = 'loginPage' )]")).click();
```

but it is not working for me.

Comment: Please post the html for this part, and try to elaborate the problem.

Comment: Hi Vikas , i have posted it in the heading . I am posting it again below      <a href=“loginPage” class=“loginBtn” data-toggle=“modal” data-target=“rnr-loginPanel”>Login</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a syntax problem with the *contains* keyword in your xpath. Following should work -

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'loginPage')]")).click();
```

Also, a better and easier way would be

```
driver.findElement(By.className("loginBtn")).click();
```